# how to use if condition in selenium web driver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

how to use if condition in

```
driver.findelement(By.xpath("id").sendkey("");
```

here for example

```
 if (xplath(id=253).click else xpath(id=888).sendkey("admin");)
```

Comment: If `id` is 253 you want to use `click`, and if `id` is 888 you want to type something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First check which element is there. Whether it's id = 253 or id = 888. We can simply use findelements in java to achieve this.

```
if(driver.findElements(by.xpath("//*[@id=253]")).size>0)
{
  //element exists with id = 253 
  // do the stuff
} else
{
   //element do not exist with id = 253. 
   //element with id - 888 exists
   // do the stuff
}
```

Hope this helps. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try this way, First find the webelement `253` , if id `253` is not getting find then, your code execution jump to the `catch` block.

```
try
    {
        WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("253"));

        if(element.isDisplayed() && element.isEnabled())
        {
            element.click();
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        WebElement element_1 = driver.findElement(By.id("888"));

        if(element_1.isDisplayed() && element_1.isEnabled())
        {
            element_1.sendKeys("admin");
        }
    }
```